# How to protect database credentials in uft

Tags: hp-uft

I have this connection string in library to connect to sql server.

```
Function db()
connectionnameDev = "Description=connect to hh dev;DRIVER=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server;SERVER=xxx;UID=xxx;PWD=#xxx%;Trusted_Connection=No;APP=UFTBase;WSID=L-XP9550-xxx;"
    Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    objConnection.Open connectionnameDev
End Function
```

This library is shared across the team. Now, everyone has access to the credentials. Each person has own database credentials. When they run scripts, they should run with their own credentials. What would be the correct approach to protect the database credentials so each person can run scripts with their own credentials?

Comment: You can store the encrypted credentials in an external file. Whenever you wish to use them, just fetch the encrypted credentials, pass them to a function that decrypts the credentials and use the decrypted credentials in the Connection string. Though, it would still be possible to get access to these credentials but it would not be as easy as it is now. P.S. There may be better ways.

Comment: Set up `SQL Server` to accept Windows authentication and each user could just connect without needing to provide userid and password as it will accept them via their windows login, as whoever they are signed into the PC as.

Answer (score 0):

If this is part of a framework, here's one idea we used in one of the teams I worked at. Our framework loaded multiple function libraries from ALM, but there was one function library that was always locally referenced, called "Load_myCredentials.qfl".

Each team member can have their credentials saved as global parameters/variables in a qfl file in their local C: drive, and the framework can just load this as a function library. Then the password becomes available throughout the test, yet the password does not become visible in any results. All you have to do is change the first line of your function db(), and parameterize the password part.